# Timing a function in C

Tags: c, function, time

I'm trying to find out the time it takes for a function to execute in C.
What i'm trying is the following:

```
#include <time.h>

time_t start;
time_t finish;
double seconds;

time(&start);
FUNCTION
time(&finish);

seconds = difftime(finish,start);

printf("Time taken is %.f", seconds);
```

However, the returned value is always the same for different functions: 1389133144 seconds.

Any help? 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed the retval from time()?

Comment: Do you get any compile warning?  If you're not including `stdio.h` then `printf` may be implicitly prototyped to take `int` arguments and casting your doubles lossily.

Comment: @tommyo what do you mean? shouldn't time() give you the current calendar time?

Comment: @evilotto no i included stdio.h as well, i simply didnt put them in this code. No compiler errors at all.

Comment: Using your code with a for loop instead of a function and changing number of iterations, it seems to be correct. Comparing it with the unix utility  `time`

Comment: Please paste your real code.  the value you are getting - 1389133144 - is suspiciously close to the current unix time.

Comment: How long does the function take to execute?  The `time()` function only reports on whole seconds, so unless your function is taking multiple seconds to run, you are most likely to get the same result twice from `time()`.

Answer (score 1):

Other approach I commonly use is something like this:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

//this is from http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~peter/ipp/
#define GET_TIME(now) { \
   struct timeval t; \
   gettimeofday(&t, NULL); \
   now = t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec/1000000.0; \
}

//in your code
double start, end;
GET_TIME(start);
//... do some stuff...
GET_TIME(end);

printf("TOTAL TIME = %f secs\n", end-start);
```

Comment: i'm using your method, but now, all i get is 0 seconds all the time

Comment: strange, i've tested right now putting a for loop (for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) in the ...do some stuff part and i get TOTAL TIME = 0.000015 secs. Probably you need to paste your entire code to see if something is causing this strange behavior

Comment: If you get 0 may be it's correct and your function takes no time to run

Comment: My bad! I multiplied both finish and start by 1000000 and got a result :) thanks a lot!

Comment: I tend to avoid doing the computation in the GET_TIME macro; I minimize the extraneous activity between the first and second call.  Otherwise, I do pretty much as you're doing.  Beware that this can be confused/confusing if the system clock is adjusted (perhaps by NTP or SNTP daemons) while your test is running.  If you have [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) you may be able to use CLOCK_MONOTONIC to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 1):

The `time` function returns the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC). If the argument is non-`NULL`, it also stores the time in it.

1389133144 is actually a pretty reasonable timestamp, it is 2014-01-07 22:19:04.

However, the `time` function is not a very good tool to measure the run time of a function, since the precision is very low. Consider using `gettimeofday`, `clock_gettime` or simply `clock`, all of which should be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the time calculations, its in the format specifier for the `printf()` statement. You are using "%.f", where you probably want "%f". The . means precision in this context.